# Dynamic menu in JSF

Tags: jsf, dynamic, menu

I am trying to implement a dynamic menu with JSF2/RichFaces. The idea is simple, the menu is defined in the database, and depends on the connected user.

The menu is correctly generated, but the action is not working, and I don't understand why.
This is my JSF code:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionMenu.menus}" var="menu"><!-- Menus -->
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="${menu.label}">${menu.label}</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" id="sub-${menu.label}">
            <c:forEach items="${menu.submenus}" var="submenu"><!-- Sub menus -->
                <li>
                    <a4j:commandLink value="${submenu.label}" action="${sessionMenu.action}"/>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

`${sessionMenu.action}` returns a string which should redirect to another page (defined as a navigation-case in the faces-config file).
I also tried to replace the action with a hard-coded string, and it works, I guess that the problem arrives with the EL which is not correctly interpreted.

If some one can help me to understand what is wrong?

**Edit**:
Here is an example of the links generated:

```
<a id="mainForm:j_id_g_0_2_0_2" onclick="RichFaces.ajax("mainForm:j_id_g_0_2_0_2",event,{"incId":"1"} );return false;" name="mainForm:j_id_g_0_2_0_2" href="#">Screen</a>
```

This one was generated dynamically and it does nothing;

```
<a id="mainForm:j_id_g_0_2_0_4" onclick="RichFaces.ajax("mainForm:j_id_g_0_2_0_4",event,{"incId":"1"} );return false;" name="mainForm:j_id_g_0_2_0_4" href="#">Screen</a>
```

And this one used a static string and the redirection is working properly.

These 2 links were generated in the same page and on the same request.

Comment: Have you looked at the output for the `a4j:commandLink` in the developer console?

Comment: Yes, but I can't see any difference between the dynamic or hardcoded string :(

Comment: Could you post examples of what the generated link looks like?

Comment: 1) This all is in a form, right? 2) The `#{sessionMenu.menus}` is guaranteed to be exactly the same during postback? 3) Why an ajax command link with a navigation case instead of a normal GET link for plain page-to-page navigation? (UX/SEO killer) 4) Why `${}` instead of `#{}`? (they behave both **exactly** the same in Facelets and there's no point of writing JSF  EL in JSP EL style)

Comment: **@BalusC:** 1) Yes. 2)the `sessionMenu` is session scoped and is not rebuilt during the session. 3) Because we have some actions to do when the user leaves a page (check/update data) 4) Just by mistake ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it working, I just changed the action value to the method name as it is defined in my bean, that means:

```
<a4j:commandLink value="#{submenu.label}" action="#{sessionMenu.getAction()}" />
```

If some one can explain why, I am curious.